# android: How to compress a video?

Tags: android, android-manifest, performance, android-framework

In my app, the user can upload a captured video into a database. Since the captured video is quite large it'll take long time to get uploaded. So I need to know how can I compress that capturing video.

I have tried following code

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);                                 
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY,0);    
startActivityForResult(intent, SOME_NUMBER);
```

But regardless of whatever the quality level I put there it gives me same quality videos.

My question:So tell me a way to fix this or suggest me a way to compress a captured video?

thanks